# Subspace Of Continuous Functions On The Unit Interval

Tags: functional-analysis

Stumbled upon this in an example in a book I am reading:

let
\begin{align*}
X:=\left\{ f \in \mathcal{C}^0\left( \left[0, 1 \right] \right)\vert f\left( 0 \right) = 0\right\}
\end{align*}
equipped with the norm $\left\Vert f  \right\Vert_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in \left[0, 1 \right]} \left\vert f \left(x \right) \right\vert$.

And
\begin{align*}
Y:=\left\{ f \in X \left\vert \int_0^1 f\left( x \right) \, \mathcal{d}x = 0 \right. \right\}
\end{align*}

then $X$ is a Banachspace and $Y$ is a closed subspace.

I am not really familiar with concepts of Functionalanalysis yet, so I dont see, where those two statements come from. Intuitively it should be that the Banach property of $X$ comes from $\mathcal{C}^0$? And to show that $Y$ is closed one would have to show for a sequence in $Y$ that it converges to a limit in $Y$?

Comment: I suppose the norm defined on $X$ is the supremum norm?

Comment: Yes, edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is a subspace of $C^0([0,1])$, which is complete (with the sup norm). Hence, in order to show that $X$ is complete as well, it suffices to show that $X$ is closed but that is indeed true: if $(f_n)\subset X$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\to 0$, then $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. So $f_n(0)\to f(0)$, but $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$. Therefore $f(0)=0$ and we get that $f\in X$.

Similarly, to show that $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$, let $(f_n)\subset Y$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\to 0$. Then $\displaystyle{|\int_0^1f(x)dx-\int_0^1f_n(x)dx|\leq \int_0^1|f(x)-f_n(x)|dx\leq\|f_n-f\|_\infty\to0}$, hence $\displaystyle{\int_0^1f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx=0}$ and the equality $f(0)=0$ is also established as above, yielding $f\in Y$.

Comment: Is there a name to search for, looking for the argument: closed subspace of banach is banach? Or is this a common argument?

Comment: What you're asking is an elementary proposition in functional analysis, you can try proving it as an exercise: Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space and $M$ a linear subspace of $X$. Prove that M is a Banach space if and only if $M$ is a closed subset of $X$.
 (if you need any help, I can provide hints/ details)

Comment: Okay, thank you! Ill try it.

Comment: So in this case I just need that a closed subspace of a banach space is banach. But that just follows bc. as X is a Banach space and M is closed, i.e. every converging sequence has limit in M, this also holds for Cauchy-sequences. Thus, M is Banach.Edit: Not qute sure I have to tag you, for you to get a notification @JustDroppedIn

Comment: @Abbraxas exactly